# How to have internal element of text node include text after element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Authors of an xml document did not include all the text inside an element that will be converted to a hyperlink.  I would like to process or pre-process the xml to include the necessary text.  I find this hard to describe but a simple example should show what I'm attempting.
I'm using XSLT 2.0.  I already do regular expression processing for various situations but can't figure this out.

I know how to do this with perl/python regular expression but I can't figure out how to approach this with XSLT.

Here is 'very' simplfied xml from an author in which they left out the ' (Sheet 3)' from the glink element.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <para>
        Go look at figure <glink refid=1>Figure 22</glink> (Sheet 3). Then go do something else.
    </para>
</root>
```

Here is what I'd like it to convert to where the ' (Sheet 3)' is now inside the glink tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <para>
        Go look at figure <glink refid=1>Figure 22 (Sheet 3)</glink>. Then go do something else.
    </para>
</root>
```

The case when this conversion should happen is when there is a glink element followed by (this regular expression):

```
\s\(Sheet \d\)
```

I currently have 2 XSLTs.  The first pre-processes the XML to convert a number of other situations (using regular expression/xsl:analyze-string).  The second XSLT to convert from pre-processed xml to HTML.  The second XSLT has a template to handle glink elements and turn it into a hyperlink but the hyperlink should be including the Sheet information.

I would assume that it is easier to pre-process this first and leave the 2nd XSLT alone, but I always appreciate better ways.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your `glink` attribute needs some quotes to make it a well-formed XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce the use of regex functions, I would use this approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="glink">
    <xsl:variable name="vAnalyzedString">
        <xsl:analyze-string 
            select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]"
            regex="^\s*\(Sheet\s+\d+\)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <match>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </match>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <no-match>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </no-match>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="$vAnalyzedString/match/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="$vAnalyzedString/no-match/text()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::glink]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
   <para>
        Go look at figure <glink refid="1">Figure 22 (Sheet 3)</glink>. Then go do something else.
    </para>
</root>
```

**Do note**: all `glink` are processed but none of those text nodes being the first siblings. It's posible to use `xsl:analize-string` instruction, but you will need to declare a variable with partial results and then navegate those results. Also, this approach might easily let you further processing those (now) text nodes and it has **only one regex processing**.

Comment: In Saxon-HE 9.4.0.4J jar, you'll get error that analyze-string does not like empty select attribute.  Using 9.9 did not have this problem.  Because I'm not ready to do regression testing, I put a `<xsl:choose>` block around the regex test to test if select is empty and if so, then output `<match></match><no-match></no-match>`.

Comment: Also due to the simplicity and straightforwardness of solution, I was able to incorporate straight into the conversion to html instead of the pre-process transform.  Because the xhtml being produced has a namespace, when applying the templates, I had to change the select to `$vAnalyzedString/*[local-name()='match']/text()`.

Comment: @beakerchi About the analyze-string complain: don't use conditional `xsl:choose` instruction, just add a predicate to the rule like `glink[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]]` that will process only the `glink` that have a text node as first following sibling (of course, the cost will be performing the test for every `glink`... wich you will do already with the `xsl:choose`)

Comment: @beakerchi About namespace: the common convention for namespace declaration is placing it in the `xsl:stylesheet` element adding the prefix to the `exclude-result-prefix` attribute. Something like `xmlns:my="dummy"` and then use it in the literal result element `<my:match>` and in the selection `$vAnalyzedString/my:match/text()`

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer has the right approach but I would sharpen the regular expression pattern and the match patterns:

```
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">\s\(Sheet \d\)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="pattern2" as="xs:string" select="'^' || $pattern"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pattern3" as="xs:string" select="'^(' || $pattern || ')(.*)'"/>

  <xsl:template match="glink[@refid][following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[matches(., $pattern2)]]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:value-of select=". || replace(following-sibling::node()[1], $pattern3, '$1', 's')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::glink[@refid]]][matches(., $pattern2)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern3, '$2', 's')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9z/1

Otherwise I think the matches and replacements happen for more than a `glink` followed (directly?) by that pattern, as you can see in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9z/2.

The code I posted uses XPath 3.1's `||` string concatenation operator but if an XSLT 2 processor is the target that could of course be replaced with a normal `concat` function call.

Comment: I also appreciate this solution in addition the the fiddles, but 2 things. 1. maybe change your first sentence from 'The existing answer' to pointing to the actual answer you are referring to.  I got slightly caught up trying to figure out what was wrong with Alejandro's answer which isn't what you were referring too.

Comment: 2. I played with the fiddle of zx485 for a while trying to see why it didn't always work and I thought that the solution just needed to put a `^` in front of the regex so it would not try to pull in Sheet info if the match didn't occur at the beginning of the text node i.e. change it to `^\s(\(Sheet \d\)).*` but that did not make a difference.  If you have time could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two templates in combination with the *Identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="glink">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|text()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(following::text()[1],'\s(\(Sheet \d\)).*',' $1'))" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::glink]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(.,'\s\(Sheet \d\)(.*)',' $1'))" />
</xsl:template>
```

The first one includes the `(Sheet 3)` string into `glink` and the second one excludes `(Sheet 3)` from the following `text()` node.

**The result is:**

```
<root>
    <para>
        Go look at figure <glink refid="1">Figure 22 (Sheet 3)</glink>. Then go do something else.</para>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as Martin Honnen showed, this did not work for the following condition `<para>
        Go look at figure <glink refid="2">Figure 23</glink>Then go do something else. (Sheet 3). 
    </para>`.  I thought I could just add a carrot `^` to the front of the regex but that did not make it work.  I asked Martin to explain why it would not but maybe you could too?